# Issue with counting entries of two labels at once

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to count the entries of two labels at once (one query with 2x `match` and 2x `with` and one `return`). My solution works fine, at least if for both labels one entry already exist.

When no entry is present at all, the query returns nothing instead of `0, 0`. Wired: When I execute both parts one after another against the empty space, it works.

**Here are the queries:**

This is the desired query (works not in case of an empty database):

```
match (all:cars) with count(all) AS countCars
match (blackCars:cars:black) with countCars, count(blackCars) AS countBlackCars
return countCars, countBlackCars
```

If I split these into two queries, they work also in case of an empty database:

```
match (all:cars) with count(all) AS countCars return countCars
match (blackCars:cars:black) with count(blackCars) AS countBlackCars return countBlackCars
```

Is there an explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. The solution is to avoid the count before return! Thus, a correct solution is `match (all:cars) with all match (blackCars:cars:black) with all, blackCars return count(all), count(blackCars)`.

Comment: You don't need the `WITH` clauses.

Comment: Also, your question asked for an explanation of the inconsistent behavior, but your answer did not do that.